# Building War file via including Avro auto generated classes

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, gradle, avro

I've recently started using Avro and Kafka in my spring boot project. Now I've googled this and can't seem to find a straight answer.

When I build my war via my gradle build file, can I include the classes autogenerated from Avro schema?

Look at the war file when its exploded it doesnt seem to include those classes.

Here is my build.gradle file.

Many thanks for reading this question and if you have the time to help!

```
plugins {
    id "org.springframework.boot" version "2.4.2"
    id 'io.spring.dependency-management' version '1.0.8.RELEASE'
    id 'java'
    id "com.commercehub.gradle.plugin.avro" version "0.21.0"
    id "idea"

}
group 'com.test.tge-auth-service'
version '1.0'

java {
    sourceCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_14
    targetCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_14
}

ext {
    avroVersion = "1.10.1"
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    jcenter()
    maven {
        url "https://packages.confluent.io/maven/"
    }
}

avro {
    createSetters = true
    fieldVisibility = "PRIVATE"
}

//apply plugin: "war"

dependencies {
//    providedRuntime 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-tomcat'

    compile group: 'co.elastic.logging', name: 'logback-ecs-encoder', version: '0.5.2'
    compile group: 'com.amazonaws', name: 'aws-java-sdk', version: '1.11.860'

    compile group: 'io.springfox', name: 'springfox-swagger-ui', version: '3.0.0'
    compile group: 'io.springfox', name: 'springfox-boot-starter', version: '3.0.0'

    compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-elasticsearch')
    compile group: 'org.springframework.boot', name: 'spring-boot-starter-data-mongodb', version: '2.3.3.RELEASE'
    compile group: 'org.springframework.data', name: 'spring-data-elasticsearch', version: '4.0.4.RELEASE'
    compile group: 'org.springframework.boot', name: 'spring-boot-starter-data-jpa', version: '2.3.3.RELEASE'
    compile group: 'org.springframework.boot', name: 'spring-boot-starter-security', version: '2.3.3.RELEASE'
    compile group: 'org.springframework.security', name: 'spring-security-oauth2-client', version: '5.4.0'
    compile group: 'org.springframework.boot', name: 'spring-boot-starter-validation', version: '2.4.2'
    compile group: 'org.springframework.kafka', name: 'spring-kafka', version: '2.6.5'

    compile group: 'javax.validation', name: 'validation-api', version: '2.0.1.Final'
    compile group: 'com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype', name: 'jackson-datatype-jsr310', version: '2.11.2'

    compile group: 'mysql', name: 'mysql-connector-java', version: '8.0.21'

    compile group: 'io.jsonwebtoken', name: 'jjwt', version: '0.9.1'
    compile group: 'org.openapitools', name: 'jackson-databind-nullable', version: '0.2.1'

    compile group: 'commons-io', name: 'commons-io', version: '2.6'
    compile group: 'org.apache.commons', name: 'commons-collections4', version: '4.4'
    compile group: 'org.apache.commons', name: 'commons-lang3', version: '3.11'
    compile group: 'org.passay', name: 'passay', version: '1.6.0'
    compile group: 'com.google.guava', name: 'guava', version: '30.0-jre'

    compile group: 'io.confluent', name: 'kafka-schema-registry-client', version: '6.0.0'
    compile group: 'io.confluent', name: 'kafka-avro-serializer', version: '6.0.0'
    compile group: 'io.confluent', name: 'monitoring-interceptors', version: '6.0.0'
    compile(group: 'io.confluent', name: 'kafka-streams-avro-serde', version:'6.0.0') {
        exclude(module: 'log4j-over-slf4j')
    }

    compile "org.apache.avro:avro:1.10.1"
    implementation "org.apache.avro:avro:${avroVersion}"

    compileOnly 'org.projectlombok:lombok:1.18.12'
    annotationProcessor 'org.projectlombok:lombok:1.18.12'

    implementation 'com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk-s3'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web'

    testCompile group: 'junit', name: 'junit', version: '4.12'
    testCompileOnly 'org.projectlombok:lombok:1.18.12'
    testAnnotationProcessor 'org.projectlombok:lombok:1.18.12'

    testImplementation('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test') {
        exclude group: 'org.junit.vintage', module: 'junit-vintage-engine'
    }

    jar {
        manifest {
            attributes(
                    'Main-Class': 'com.test.SpringBootPersistenceApplication'
            )
        }
        from {
            configurations.runtimeClasspath.collect { it.isDirectory() ? it : zipTree(it) }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so, for me what worked was a rebuild of the project in Intellij.